# Get Facebook iframe params

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If a user clicks 'Accept' on a request, they will see an iframe with my site in it.

The facebook url (that has the iframe), looks something like this:

https://apps.facebook.com/[request_id]/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=[request_ids]&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request

How can i get the 'request_id' from the iframe url??

Is there a method/API for that in the JS library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `php`

you can retrieve `request_id` by `$_GET['request_id'] or $_REQUEST['request_id']`

if you are using `javascript`

This is just one implementation of getting requests parameters in javascript, there are better implementations as well, i stated an example.

```
var Request = { 
    parameter: function(name) {
        return this.parameters()[name];
    },

    parameters: function() {
        var result = {};
        var url = window.location.href;
        var parameters = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

        for(var i = 0;  i < parameters.length; i++) {
            var parameter = parameters[i].split('=');
            result[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
        }
        return result;
    }
 }
```

`var request_id = parameters['request_id'];`

Get url from `iframe`

> document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href

Hope this is what you require

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work (the javascript part). It gets the URL of my website, not the URL of the iFrame. Any ideas?

Comment: isn't the url of the iframe present in its src attr ? updated my answer

Comment: Hello Dhiraj. The src is not present in the iframe. I looks like this: `<iframe class="smart_sizing_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas_fb_https" src='javascript:""' height="800" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" oallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="height: 389px;"></iframe>` The `$_GET['request_ids']` is no longer possible. Interesting if there is a JS workaround. Any ideas?